# Wix: Show installed/failed icons during install progress

Tags: wix, wix3.6, wix3.7, wix-extension, wix3.8

In installation progress screen, i have added (success/failure) icons for each feature, on completion of each feature I need to show the success/failure icon (during installation progress).

I was trying to use control events 
(ActionData, ActionText, SetProgress, TimeRemaining, ScriptInProgress)
but didn't succeed

Please help on this.

Thanks,
Saran

Answer (score 1):

The items in the MSI are not installed one feature at a time. For example, all the files are installed in a single action. You cannot have a UI that lights up first one feature then another as the install proceeds because that's not what's happening. That's part of why there is a progress bar.

Note also that there is no such thing as a feature that installs and another that fails to install. The installation is a transaction and if it fails everything rolls back and restores the system to its previous state.